# Rate stars in css does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to add rating stars to my project , I tried a lot of codes but none works fine.

here is the result :[image: img]

Comment: Please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/vlpkh

Comment: could you please briefly explain issue , codepen seems to be working fine

Comment: I tried to copy past this code in my files and then I got some shapes other than stars ,I don't know if I have to add something else or my browser doesn't support this kind of css, could you please help me by providing other solution please ?

Comment: If I m not wrong, it works in codepen but when copy same to your project , you are getting different shapes other than stars right??

Comment: yes exactly ..........

Comment: Chris, are you getting an console errors

Comment: <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Could you please inmport font awesome through link tag ,issue is that font awesome css not getting imported in your local code?

Comment: Please try to copy the code from this codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/dWZjGW

Comment: great answer ! thank you so much it works fine !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is that the font awesome css are not getting imported,

Please use below option

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Codpen- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/dWZjGW